# JBehave with Serenity - report can't find test scenarios

Tags: maven, jbehave, serenity-bdd

Using Jbehave, my runner class extends JUnitStories, I can generate the plain-style report with the following:

```
    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
    Class<? extends Embeddable > embeddableClass = this.getClass();
        return new MostUsefulConfiguration().useStoryLoader(new LoadFromClasspath(embeddableClass))
            .useStoryControls(new StoryControls().doResetStateBeforeScenario(false).useStoryMetaPrefix("story_").useScenarioMetaPrefix("scenario_"))
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                new StoryReporterBuilder()
                .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass))
                .withDefaultFormats().withFormats(CONSOLE, HTML).withFailureTrace(true)
                .withFailureTraceCompression(true));
}
```

Now I want to integrate JBehave with Serenity for better looking reports ^_^. So I changed my runner class to inherit from SerenityStories instead. After adding dependencies and running via maven, the tests pass. However, the Serenity generated report always sees '0 test scenarios'.

I saw that SerenityStories inherits JUnitStories, and overrides the configuration() method as well.

How can I make Serenity see my test scenarios? Do I need to override the configuration() method differently? And how?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by creating a new maven project instead.
Used the archetype: 'serenity-jbehave-archetype'.
There will be a pre-created & empty runner class that inherits SerenityStories.
I just then merged my files to this new project.
As for the runner class, I've overridden the methods stepsFactory() and storyPaths() to match my steps/stories.

Hope that made sense. Thanks!